# Why does not work old in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have from:

`{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'announcements', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'GET')) }}`

And checkbox in form:

```
{{Form::checkbox('only_subscriptions', '1', old('only_subscriptions'))}}
```

After submit I get empty `old()`:

```
old('only_subscriptions')
```

Comment: Are you flashing the input to the session? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#old-input

Comment: I return object of data afetr submit: `return View::make('announcements.index', [
            "announcements" => $announcements,
            "categories" => $categories,
            "country" => $country,
            "city" => $city
        ]);`

Comment: So, I need to return `->withInput();` with data?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're trying to do so it's hard to say what you should do... `old()` is used to recall the previously submitted data in that particular session...

Comment: Can you share example when I return data in view and with withInput?

Comment: You have to explain better what is it you are trying to do, I can share many examples, but I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, your question is poorly worded.

Comment: I have form, that I submit, after submit I need to save previous values in form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137843/discussion-between-upful-and-darama).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `->withInput()` in `redirect()`, not in `view()`.